# Listing total number of features into an ArcGIS Online feature pop-up when the service consists of grouped features

Tags: arcgis-online, popup, feature-service, arcade

I'm trying to use the count function to list the total number of features in a feature pop-up.  I can do this through configure pop-up/add expression `Count($layer)` if the feature service consists of separate features, but I cannot if the features are grouped.  If the features are grouped when publishing the service, the "Globals" tab in the add expression window doesn't list the same functions, most importantly the `$layer` functionality.

Is it still possible to perform the count?

I'd like to avoid ungrouping and republishing all of my services, if possible.  In the image below, you'll see the add expression window for the same feature.  On the left, the feature was published on it's own--it will look this way if published with multiple features, as well.  On the right, it was published as a group.

[image]